# Flutter widget only rendered on refresh

Tags: flutter, charts, widget, rendering

I created a Chart widge but it is only rendered when refreshing the app in VSCode. I'm passing the List _pieChartSections to the widget and it contains always data, also on the initial launch of the app.

Why isn't widget shown on the initial launch?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<PieChartSectionData>? _pieChartSections = myFunc.buildChrtSections(
        Provider.of<GamesProv>(context, listen: false).gamesInRegion,
        Provider.of<SkUserProfileProv>(context).skUser!.userAchievements);
    debugPrint(_pieChartSections![0].radius.toString());  //_pieChartSections has always data
    return _pieChartSections.isNotEmpty
        ? Scaffold(
            //appBar: const MyAppBar(),
            body: GamePiechart(pieChartSegments: _pieChartSections),
          )
        : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
  }
}

class GamePiechart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<PieChartSectionData>? pieChartSegments;

  const GamePiechart({this.pieChartSegments, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PieChart(
      PieChartData(
        //centerSpaceColor: Colors.cyan,
        startDegreeOffset: 140,
        borderData: FlBorderData(
          show: false,
        ),
        sectionsSpace: 4,
        centerSpaceRadius: 62,
        sections: pieChartSegments,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am assuming the _pieChartsSection is empty and that's why you are showing the progress bar. Check the logic that retrieves the data for the _pieChartsSection.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking this on every load and it always has data.